# Link to Outlook Attachment

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, attachments

When you attach a document to an outlook email, a copy of the document is created and stored somewhere. You can obviously link to any location in the body of outlook. A hyperlink to a local document will not be useful to a recipient on another machine (without access to the local drive).

But, is there a way to hyperlink to an attached file? I don't think that there is any native way to do this, but is there any possible solution?

If it matters, the email will only be read by outlook. (i.e. intra office).

Comment: In the case of an attachment the file is embedded within the email itself.  Internally many companies use Microsoft sharepoint which integrates with exchange/outlook.  You can also use a service like Dropbox or roll your own Dropbox like service with ownCloud.

Comment: Please don't double post.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852618/hyperlink-to-outlook-attachment

Answer (score -1):

In HTML, there's a tag called anchor. If you use an anchor tag, you can reference the anchor in the start of the e-mail. Clicking on it takes you a different part in the e-mail. It doesn't link directly to the attachment (it doesn't open it), but it takes you close. If you want people to open the attachment, put it on a network drive, or OneDrive for Business (which runs on SharePoint)

References:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/11/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/